# JavaScript - Why doesn't my code run when "Document.querySelector().value" is outside function + how do I get function to run on input number change?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, constants, addeventlistener

I would like some help please.

I managed to make my code work after finding a similar question on Stack Overflow, but the method I've been trying previously doesn't seem to work at all.

My code is very simple, if the number is 2 and I click the button, the message will say "Correct". If the number is anything else, it will say "Wrong".

**Below is the HTML**

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <input type="number">
      <p>Message</p>
      <button>Update</button>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

**Here is the JavaScript code that works**
*[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/mangomangocodexusi/pen/QWmqyqE)*

```
const message = document.querySelector("p")
const button = document.querySelector("button")


function myFunction() {
const number = document.querySelector("input").value;
if (parseInt(number) === 2)  {
  message.textContent = "Correct"
  } else message.textContent = "Wrong!"
}

button.addEventListener("click", myFunction)
```

**Here is the code that doesn't work**
[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/mangomangocodexusi/pen/oNqGboQ)

```
const message = document.querySelector("p")
const button = document.querySelector("button")
const number = document.querySelector("input").value


function myFunction() {
if (parseInt(number) === 2)  {
  message.textContent = "Correct"
  } else message.textContent = "Wrong!"
}

button.addEventListener("click", myFunction)
```

**My question is, why doesn't my second JavaScript code work? Is it possible to keep the number const outside of the function (keep the const variable global)?**

As the tutorials I'm watching suggest you keep variables outside functions to prevent DRY.

**Also, how can I get the code to run without having to click the "update" button each time
?**

e.g. if I type 2, the message will automatically say "Correct".

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You're setting `number` when the page is first loaded, before the user has entered anything into the input.

Comment: `const number = document.querySelector("input").value` does not keep updating. It reads the value at that moment in time and store it. To follow the approach they are talking about `const number = document.querySelector("input");` and when you want the value, reference it `if (+number.value === 2){`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation and help you've both given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const number needs to be in the function, otherwise the const will be null always

```
function myFunction() {

const number = document.querySelector("input").value
if (parseInt(number) === 2)  {
  message.textContent = "Correct"
  } else message.textContent = "Wrong!"
}
```

Live update on keyup inputfield

```
const inputfield = document.querySelector("input");
inputfield.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jayr, this is exactly what I've been looking for, clear and concise, I really appreciate it.